# Studying the PCIe/CXL/CCIX internals at home

Tags: fpga, pcie

Could anybody recommend me a good starting point for self-studying the PCIe internals?
I imagine some kind of an FPGA-based course, covering PCIe endpoint, root complex and switching functionalities. Ultimately, I would like to evolve my learning path towards CXL and CCIX. Unfortunately, I could not find anything appropriate and highly rated on platforms like Udemy and Coursera.

I would highly appreciate any kind of guidance on the topic, since I am eager to learn  everything related to those protocols.

Comment: Possible value? [Here](https://www.techtarget.com/searchstorage/post/CXL-A-Basic-Tutorial)

Comment: [maybe](https://youtu.be/MB2xF96HU_0)

Comment: PCIe courses are there but few, and so expensive for individuals. Find one in MindShare. Their course book is also available as PDF, which is so far the best book I have read on understanding PCI/PCIe technology.